# How to implement generic collection lookup method that can return class or nullable struct?

Tags: c#, generics

I want a typed lookup helper function for a heterogenous collection: It should return a struct or class, else null if the item is not found.
Below is an example using a trivial collection lookup, but it could be a database call or whatever.

Is there any way to achieve this with a single method signature?

```
    public T GetClass<T>(string key)  where T : class
    {
        object o;
        if (Contents.TryGetValue(key, out o))
        {
            return o as T;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public T? GetStruct<T>(string key) where T : struct
    {
        object o;
        if (Contents.TryGetValue(key, out o))
        {
            if (o is T)
            {
                return (T?) o;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What I've already tried:

- I understand that generic restrictions can't be used to disambiguate overloads. So I can't simply give these two methods the same name.
- Returning `(Default) T` isn't an option, since 0 is a valid int value.
- I have tried calling with `<int ?>` as the type, but as discussed, `Nullable<T>` isn't a reference type.

Is there some way to indicate that I'm going to return a boxed int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method works for both classes and nullable structures:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string key)
{
    object o;
    if (Contents.TryGetValue(key, out o))
    {
        if (o is T)
        {
            return (T)o;
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

*Usage:*

```
int?   result1 = GetValue<int?>("someInt");
string result2 = GetValue<string>("someString");
```

Notice how the `?` is part of generic type argument and not defined by the method on the return type.

Comment: I half like this - but it *allows* you to call it as `GetClass<int>` and return 0 for "found with value 0" and "not found" indistinguishably. Indeed, you could accidentally miss out the second `?` in your sample usage and get a pretty subtle bug. (`result1` would *never* be null, but you would expect it to be)

Comment: I think the default for int? is null

Comment: But what if the value you are looking up is a regular int: i think the (o is int?) will fail bc int? is not an int.

Comment: @akatakritos: Jon is pointing out that you could also call `GetValue<int>` which would return `0` and not `null`. Of course, one could add a runtime check to the method to prevent this. My code works also for regular ints, because `(object)42 is int?` is true.

Comment: akatakritos: int? is an alias for Nullable<int> nullable is a struct so it will never be null. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Comment: I'll call this a winner - with the addition of a runtime check to address the potential usage error identified by @Jon. I added `Type t = typeof(T); if (t.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) == null) { throw new ArgumentException(t.ToString() + " is not a reference type or Nullable"); }`

Comment: @SteveWeil: If *you* like this, then for your question, that's great (and accept the answer). I probably wouldn't use it myself - preferring separate methods with different names - but it sounds like you should accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge @Jon (I'm new here). If it was only this single entry point, then I might agree with you and use two methods. However I often build upon this with methods like SetIfNotSet<T>() and then I get an undesirable explosion of methods. (Or I'm adding logging or error handling to the accessor and don't want to duplicate that code as well.)

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to achieve this with a single method signature?

There's a [*horrible*](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround.aspx) (truly hideous) way to do it using optional parameters so that the calling code can look the same in both cases. It's icky though.

Options:

- Return a `Tuple<T, bool>` instead of using nullity
- Use an `out` parameter (like `int.TryParse` etc)
- Use different method names

Note that by signalling the absence of a value separately, you can make `null` a valid "found" result, which can be useful sometimes. Or you *may* want to just guarantee that it'll never be returned.

If you really want to use nullity, I'd go for the last option. I believe it will make your code clearer anyway. IMO, overloading should really only be used when the methods do *exactly* the same thing expressed using different parameters - whereas returning `Nullable<T>` as the return type in one case and `T` as the return type in the other case can't really be seen that way.

Answer (score 2):

This should do exactly what you need it to. If the requested type is a nullable type, check the underlying type before casting.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string key)
{
    object o;
    if (Contents.TryGetValue(key, out o))
    {
        if (o is T || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) == o.GetType())
        {
            return (T)o;
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

My test code:

```
Contents.Add("a string", "string value");
Contents.Add("an integer", 1);
Contents.Add("a nullable integer", new Nullable<int>(2));

// Get objects as the type we originally used.
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<string>(\"a string\") = {0}", GetValue<string>("a string")));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<int>(\"an integer\") = {0}", GetValue<int>("an integer")));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<int?>(\"a nullable integer\") = {0}", GetValue<int?>("a nullable integer")));

// Get objects as base class object.
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<object>(\"a string\") = {0}", GetValue<object>("a string")));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<object>(\"an integer\") = {0}", GetValue<object>("an integer")));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<object>(\"a nullable integer\") = {0}", GetValue<object>("a nullable integer")));

// Get the ints as the other type.
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<int?>(\"an integer\") = {0}", GetValue<int?>("an integer")));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<int>(\"a nullable integer\") = {0}", GetValue<int>("a nullable integer")));

// Attempt to get as a struct that it's not, should return default value.
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<double>(\"a string\") = {0}", GetValue<double>("a string")));

// Attempt to get as a nullable struct that it's not, or as a class that it's not, should return null.
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<double?>(\"a string\") = {0}", GetValue<double?>("a string")));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("GetValue<StringBuilder>(\"a string\") = {0}", GetValue<StringBuilder>("a string")));
```

Results:

```
GetValue<string>("a string") = string value
GetValue<int>("an integer") = 1
GetValue<int?>("a nullable integer") = 2

GetValue<object>("a string") = string value
GetValue<object>("an integer") = 1
GetValue<object>("a nullable integer") = 2

GetValue<int?>("an integer") = 1
GetValue<int>("a nullable integer") = 2

GetValue<double>("a string") = 0

GetValue<double?>("a string") = 
GetValue<StringBuilder>("a string") =
```

Comment: `(object)42 is int?` is true. There is not need for the `|| Nullable...` check.

Comment: Dang it, sometimes I hate the compiler magic around nullable. No other struct would return true for `<int> is <struct>`.